# Show that $(A\cup B)-(C \cup D) \subset (A-C)\cup (B-D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proof of the mentioned proposition is required to construct the Lebesgue Measure in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

As it is omitted in the textbook, I'm having some difficulty deducing it.

Would somebody please help me out?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps you, but if I recall correctly, the $-$ above represents *set* minus, so that if you start directly (i.e., "Let $x\in$LHS...) the proof is straightforward.

Comment: Let $x$ be an element of the LHS.  By symmetry we can assume $x\in A$. Since $x\not\in C$, the result follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $x \in (A\cup B)-(C \cup D)$ then

- $x \in A$ or $x \in B$
- $x \not \in C$
- $x \not \in D$

so

- $x \in (A-C)$ or $x \in (B-D)$

so

- $x \in (A-C)\cup (B-D)$

implying  $(A\cup B)-(C \cup D) \subset (A-C)\cup (B-D)$

Comment: Can't $x$ also be in $(A - D)$ or $(B - C)$?

Comment: @morphic: I have said any $x$ which is an element of  $(A\cup B)-(C \cup D)$ must be an element of $(A-C)\cup (B-D)$, which is what is required here.  This is a one-way statement and it does not preclude some other elements of $(A-C)\cup (B-D)$ not being elements of $(A\cup B)-(C \cup D)$.  In answer to your exact comment, an $x \in (A\cup B)-(C \cup D)$ would also be an element of $(A-D)\cup (B-C)$, but this is not important for the original question